# How can I customize Guided decision table for adding a new window using drools 6.3.0

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am a newbie to drools 6.3.0, as per our project requirement I need to customize the Guided decision table. I want to add a new window there where elements can be imported from a file and I want to drag and drop these elements on decision table cells.
If anyone can help me in this, whether this is possible using Drools 6.3.0 or not. Basically i want to customize the guided decision table as per our requirement. But not sure whether this is possible or not

Comment: Drools is open source, so you can add anything you like.

Comment: Ok, so can you give me some pointers how can I add the drag and drop functionality with decision table. I mean do I need to use any UI technology(angular, Html, javascript) or some inbuilt functionality is provided in drools